# All DateTimeFields are frozen in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a community / forum based website I'm working on in Django, and I have a timestamp that's created whenever a post or reply is created. However, the timestamps for the forum posts and replies are always frozen on the date December 24 2015, 9:28 PM. Here are my models.

```
class ForumReply(models.Model):
    by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey(ForumPost)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.body[:10])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.body[:10])

    def like_reply(self):
        self.points = F('points') + 1
        profile = User.userprofile.related.related_model.objects.filter(user=self.by)
        profile.update(points=F('points') + 10)
        self.save()

class ForumPost(models.Model):
    subforum = models.ForeignKey(SubForum)
    by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.title)

    def like_post(self):
        self.points = F('points') + 1
        profile = User.userprofile.related.related_model.objects.filter(user=self.by)
        profile.update(points=F('points') + 15)
        self.save()
```

Is there something wrong with my datetime fields that's causing it to do this? Or is it a bug with django itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are passing `timezone.now`, which is a function object. It will be evaluated only ONCE when django is loaded, since then the value will only change after you reinitialize django. You need to use `auto_now_add`:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Please read [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) for details.

**Edit:**

I was actually wrong about the first part(pointed out by @Daniel), `timezone.now` is not called when django is initialized, but `timezone.now()` will. `timezone.now` will be called every time the model object is created, which should have the desired behavior. I assume OP resolved his issue by using `auto_now_add`, but hopefully it doesn't confuse others.

Comment: I tried all forms of what I'm trying to accomplish: I tried doing `timezone.now`, `timezone.now()`, `auto_now_add=True` etc.. and it still gets the same results.

Comment: Try adding `blank=True`. I've already explained to you why `timezone.now` would not work. Also, it won't affect your existing records, it will only work for you newly created objects.

Comment: This isn't true. `timezone.now` is a callable, and this is *explicitly* supported by Django and is absolutely the right thing to do. `timezone.now()` would have the effects described, but the question as asked used `timezone.now` which would work absolutely fine.